# list up all files with a certain extension on a device

Tags: android, android-file, android-external-storage

I want to find all the files, in my case pdf's, on a device. Now I wrote this code:

```
File images = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        mImagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
            {
                return ((name.endsWith(".pdf")));
            }
        });
```

This code finds only one pdf 
`/storage/emulated/0/HTC_One_WWE_User_Guide.pdf`. I've got several other pdf's in my download folder.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Juan.

```
private void findFiles(String[] paths) {
  for (String path: paths) {
    recursiveScan(new File(path));
  }
}

private void recursiveScan(File _file) {
  File[] files = _file.listFiles();
  if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
    for (File file: files) {
      if (file.isDirectory()) recursiveScan(file);
      if (file.isFile()) {
        Log.d("Scan: ", file.toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You just need to give a File var from where to search.

Comment: Why the terrible naming? Why not call `file` -> `files` since it's the `listFiles()`? And why not call `ff` -> `file` since it's a single file?

Comment: I renamed everything locally back then it was just to test if it was working.

Comment: I still upvoted but those names were throwing me off. You should update the answer to make it clearer for others. :)

Answer (score 1):

Get a list of files from the external storage directory, and iterate said list. This should allow you to see if the extension matches pdf and then add to a list or whatever you want to do:

```
File[] file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles(); 
for (File f : file){
   if (f.isFile() && f.getpath().endswith(".pdf")) {
      //Add to your list 
   }
}
```

This wont go inside directories as far as I know, so you'll need to wrap it inside a method and do something like if `f.isDirectory()` re-call the method again to walk through the folder.

```
public void recursiveScan(File f) {
    File[] file = f.listFiles(); 
    for (File f : file){
        if (f.isDirectory()) recursiveScan(f);
        if (f.isFile() && f.getpath().endswith(".pdf")) {
            //Add to your list 
        }
    }
}
```

Which would be called something like `recursiveScan(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());`

**Disclaimer:**
I haven't tested it, so some stuff may be off, but it should give you a general idea of how to get to do it.